# get a date 6 years from now?

Tags: php, date

i want to have a date 6 years from now?

how do i do that?

Comment: May need to schedule with an escort service.

Comment: How do we submit this comment into a "best comments" category?  Amazing.

Comment: How about marking some of your 22 questions that answers with some correct answers.

Comment: ok now i know...but what if multiple answers are correct.. that would be a pity not to select them all ..

Comment: Choose the answer with the highest quality. If that fails, choose the earliest answer. If that fails give the answer to whoever has the lowest points.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime('+6 years');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
?>
```

Comment: Is that really how you do this in PHP?

Comment: I guess I am spoiled by the .NET DateTime object.

Comment: PHP offers a DateTime object as well, although its modification format matches strtotime's awesome voodoo. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: I thought with the DateTime class you could use a relative format in one line, perhaps, but this will certainly work! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); //required if not set
$date = new DateTime('1/1/1981');
$date->modify('+60 year');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Above is not affected by unix time stamp date range (before 1970 and after 2038).

Also you can directly compare dates with Comparison operators directly, no need convert them to Time stamp.

Requires PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime('+6 years');
```

you can pass that timestamp into something like strftime();
[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Still laughing about ChaosPandion's comment :)

```
echo strtotime ("+6 years");
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your description isn't very precise, but `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 years"));` might be what you need ...

Answer (score -1):

189302400 is the number of seconds in 6 years.

Get the current timestamp, then add 189302400, and then convert the timestamp to a date string.

Comment: +1 for omitting the necessary code and focusing on the timestamps

Comment: Does that six-year period include 0, 1, or 2 leap years?

(1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, etc, are not leap years.)

Comment: Good in theory, but broken in practice since it doesn't properly account for leap years. 1997-2003 needs to subtract a day since 2000 wasn't a leap year and 2003-2009 needs to add a day since both 2004 and 2008 were leap years. That even assumes you planned for at least one leap year within 6 years.

Comment: 2000 *was* a leap year: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar